# getting integer values(Starting with 0) from jtextfield

Tags: java, swing

i'm new to coding. here i am trying to concatenate two integer values n put them into a string . Problem is that it works fine only when values like 23,2,45.... are entered , when i enter value starting with 0 like 08, it only sends 8 into bnn

```
    int bn=1600;
    int bnn=Integer.parseInt(yoursectortfv.getText()); /*yoursectortfv is the name of jtextfield*/
    String ssector=""+bn+bnn;

    int now= Integer.parseInt(ssector);
    System.out.println(now);
```

Although im sure that its a problem with line 2 but in case the problem is with my code then let me know . if i still haven't actually be able to explain my problem then its like this ,basically i want my displayed number to be 160008 when i enter 08 in jtextfield but it gives 16008

Comment: Why parse int from the string returned by your text field. Just append that. `String ssector="1600"+yoursectortfv.getText();`

Comment: ahh thx. it works but what if i want a value 08 in bnn for some other purpose ,how can i get 08 in that bnn

Comment: You could also use the line you wrote to get `int bnn` but since it is an int, you will lose any leading zeroes i.e. `08` becomes '8'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is that it works fine only when values like 23,2,45.... are
>   entered , when i enter value starting with 0 like 08, it only sends 8
>   into bnn

Here `int bnn = Integer.parseInt(yoursectortfv.getText());`, you convert the `08` String to an `Integer`.
And the `toString()` representation of this `Integer` is `8`.

Here :

```
String ssector=""+bn+bnn;
```

you concatenate one String and two Integers that will be converted into String.

```
 "" + "1600" + "8"
```

It gives `"16008"` .

If you want to keep the value of the field as it was entered, `bnn` should be also a `String` :

```
String bnn=yoursectortfv.getText();
```

In this way this code (the empty `String` is not required any longer as one of the operand is now a `String`):

```
String ssector = bn+bnn;
```

will produce the result  : `"1600" + "08"`.
It gives `"160008"`as you expect.

Comment: okay it works :) but can u please explain that why 08 converts to 8 when putiing in bnn